# What type of sql execution would result in this format of InputBuffer EventInfo?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, dbcc

I am trying to trace an event that a trigger logged back to its source.  The triggered is written to capture the dbcc input buffer of the spid, however, I am not very familiar with how that functions works for different sources (stored procedures, inline sql, etc.).  The EventInfo was in the following format:

```
(@P1 int,@P2 int)DELETE FROM "dbo"."TABLE_NAME" WHERE "FIELD1" = @P1 AND "FIELD2" = @P2
```

This was logged as a 'Language Event' so I know it is not from a stored procedure.  It almost looks like a LINQ statement to me but I know for a fact no LINQ statements would ever touch that table.  What type of sql execution would result in a format like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging, I was able to determine this type of EventInfo was produced by MS Access of all things.  Hopefully this info will help someone in the future!